# What is the meaning of the notation $f_{\chi_{[a,b]}}$ where $\chi$ is the charactaristic function of $[a,b]$?

Tags: measure-theory, functions, notation

I've seen this notation appear in a handful of texts, particularly on measure theory and lebesgue integration, but I've never seen it explained and Google turns up nothing. Is it simply $f_{\chi_{[a,b]}}(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) &\text{if }x\in [a,b] \\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$?

Comment: yes it's that..

Comment: Please, this is $$f\cdot\chi_{[a,b]}$$ using the function $$\chi_{[a,b]}$$ not your $f_\mathcal{X_{[a,b]}}$. And the symbol for $\chi$ is `\chi`.

Comment: I doubt that you've seen that notation without explanation. More likely is you say $f\chi_{[a,b]}$ and misread it as $f_{\chi_{[a,b]}}$; they look very much alike.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.- Don't forget that Lebesgue integration uses very general functions and that the Riemann integration generally is based on the consideration of step functions, $g$, concisely written as
$$g(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}c_i\chi_{[a_i,b_i]}(x)$$

This gives you maybe an idea of the use of $f_{\chi_{[a,b]}}(x)=\begin{cases} f(x) &\text{if }x\in [a,b] \\0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ in which it is subunderstand that this function is just $$F(x)=f(x)\cdot\chi_{[a,b]}(x)$$ which is "a kind of step function" where the non zero parts are not right segments.

(You can see the "analogy" between $g$ and $F$  which is very significant when the $[a_i,b_i]$ intervals tend to be very small).

Comment: Please do not validate the subscript mistake.

Comment: Better explain what you want, please. My English is not good. Is it for the upvote non deserved you think? If you consider this I shall delete my answer (which was a comment really). Regards.

Comment: What? Again, the sentence "This gives you maybe an idea of the use of $f_{\chi_{[a,b]}}(x)=\cdots$" is misleading since nobody uses the notation $f_{\chi_{[a,b]}}(x)$. (Unrelated: If your answer is "a comment really", why did you post it as an answer at all?)

Comment: 1) I believed that the OP has read about the use of $f_{\chi_{[a,b]}}(x)$. ////                   2) My text was long for a comment.  ////     3) I thought your comment was equanimitory but now I think that not. ////   4) Do you want to I delete my answer? If yes, I'll do, I promise you.

Comment: Not interested in such considerations, sorry.